# How does a spinning disk respond to an impulse?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, gyroscopes

[image]

The figure shows a disk spinning with an angular velocity $\omega_z$. The disk is suspended from a long string.

I would like to know the following:

- How does the disk respond to an impulse $J$?
- What are the differential equations that describe this response?

Answer (score 1):

Let us assume that hitting the disc doesn't cause any loss of energy due to friction. We can conserve angular momentum about the center:
$$JR=I_x\omega_x$$
where $I_x=mR^2/4$
So our disc can be thought of as independently rotating about $z$ and $x$ axes. We can find the component of $\omega_x,\omega_z$ to get $\omega_{net}$ along which will be actual axes of rotation of our disc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can one say that angular momentum is conserved? Does the angular momentum not change because of the impulse?

Comment: @wSmit Indeed torque is acted by impulse, but after the impulse is acted, there is no torque. After that, we can conserve the angular momentum